# Подключение шары в домене Windows - нет прав на запись

Tags: linux, администрирование, samba

подключил linux в домен windows
пользователи входят, uid выделяются нормально.

Задача - так как это машина для нескольких человек, нужно что бы подключалась общая папка но с привилигиями конкретного пользователя

в /etc/fstab добавил такую запись
//dc.td.ru/share /media/share1 cifs user,rw,noauto,iocharset=utf8,soft,filemode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

когда захожу отпользователя подключаю шару коммандой
mount //dc.td.ru/share
Шара работает, но при этом нет возмжности записывать туда. Пишет нет прав доступа.
Как побороть это?

также как лучще всего автоматически выполнять комманду mount при подключении пользователя?

и дополнительно - кто нибудь справился с возможным подключением с использованием
pam_mount.conf.xml

Comment: Вы не передаете в команде пользователя подключения

Comment: А типа указывать, что "задействовать керберос" не надо?

Answer (score 1):

> как лучще всего автоматически выполнять комманду mount при подключении
> пользователя?

Что такое **подключение** пользователя? Если вы имеете в виду процесс входа пользователя в систему, то ответ очевидный: надо команду *mount* помещать в файл *.profile* или *.bashrc* этого пользователя.

Но тут есть проблема: команда *mount* требует рутовских привелегий. И когда бользователь будет лгинится, автоматического монтироывания не произойдёт. Есть способы обойти эту проблему, но это отдельный разговор.

Если же Вы желаете выполнить монтирование во время загрузки ОС, то надо эти диски прописываеть в таблицу */etc/fstab*. Этот способо считается устаревшим, но он самый простой и пока ещё работает.